# How to convert the secret sharing modulus?

Tags: secret-sharing

Assume $c$ is a secret number in $Z_p$ and $c = a + b$. Alice has $a$ and Bob has $b$. Is there any methods to convert the modulo $p$ to some $q$, ($c<q$, $c<p$)? That is to say, $c = a' + b'$ in $Z_q$ and $a'$, $b'$ are known by Alice and Bob respectively.

Comment: Let $c =  a + b \bmod p$ then we have $$c =  a + b + p \cdot k$$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. Now, you want to keep $c$ in the new modulus $q$ with adjustment of $a$ and $b$ such that $$c = a' + b' + q\cdot k'$$

if you let the new $c' = c \cdot p$ it is easy...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $p$ and $q$ are different primes (if $q$ divides $p$, for instance, the problem is trivial). Modulus conversion is usually not a simple task in the context of secret-sharing. The most common use-case for this type of primitives is, for example, taking a bit $b\in\{0,1\}$ that is secret-shared over a large prime $p$ as $b = a+b\bmod p$, and turning it into binary additive shares $b = a'+b'\bmod 2$ (which is ultimately $b = a'\oplus b'$. This has many applications, for instance, when you want to deal with non-arithmetic operations in Secure Multiparty Computation (e.g. secure comparisons, truncations, mathematical functions, etc.)

Most approaches to the task of secure conversion follow this technique. Let us denote $[x]_p$ when a value $x$ is secret-shared modulo $p$. Our goal is to obtain $[x\bmod q]_q$. Assume the parties already have shares of a random value $r$, unknown to either party, using both moduli $p$ and $q$. In other words, assume the parties have $[r]_p$ and $[r]_q$. Then the parties can proceed as follows:

1. Compute locally shares of $x-r$ modulo $p$ by subtracting locally their shares of $x$ with their shares of $r$.
2. Send their shares of $x-r$ to each other so that each party learns $x-r$. This keeps $x$ hidden because it is being masked by $r$, which is uniformly random and unknown to any party.
3. One of the parties adds $(x-r\bmod q)$ to his/her share of $r$ modulo $q$, which leads to $[r]_q + (x-r) = [x\bmod q]_q$.

This assumes the parties have access to the pair $([r]_p, [r]_q)$, but in many cases this is not easy to get. For example, if $q=2$, some techniques that might be useful can be found [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/207.pdf). All of this gets even trickier when active security gets into the picture.